# Não consigo instalar a referência System.ObjectModel no Projeto Android

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

Peguei um erro de referência em meu projeto `The referenced component 'System.ObjectModel' could not be found.`. Bem, pesquisei e instalei a referência desse path:`C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ObjectModel.dll`. Bem, quando terminei de instalar, sem que eu fizesse alguma coisa, apareceu esse erro:

> Project App2.Android cannot build using Android 7.1 (API Level 25 -
>   Nougat) because Android SDK platform for API Level 25 is not
>   installed. Either install it in the Android SDK Manager
>   (Tools->Android->Android SDK Manager...), or change your
>   Xamarin.Android project to target an API version that is installed.
>     0

E logo abaixo, dizendo que a referência não foi encontrada(recem instalada).

> The referenced component 'System.ObjectModel' could not be
>   found.    App2.Android

Estou pesquisando e não encontrei nada ainda. Alguém já passou por isso e poderia compartilhar?
 Eu vou instalar o android 7.1, mas o que acho mais estranho é não encontrar a referência.

**Edit 1**

Bem, desinstalei a referência(dll) e reinstalei e nada, continua com aquela exclamação amarela. Removi novamente e peguei um link na internet que recomenda fazer a instalação, via NuGet. Fiz e agora a referência não aparece na lista de referências e quando eu rodo, continua com erro de deploy, mas o warning de que a referência não foi encontrada, sumiu, mas está sem a dita cuja referência. A versão pelo NuGet é a 4.3.0 e não sei o impacto disso. Essa é a mensagem que dá saída:

> 1>Starting deploy VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone ...
>   1>Starting emulator VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone ...
>   1>C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1\tools\emulator.EXE -partition-size 512
>   -no-boot-anim -avd VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone -prop monodroid.avdname=VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone
>
> 1>Emulator VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone cannot be started.
>
> > ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Dei um clean na solution e parece que resolveu o problemas, mas somente após eu limpar a solution é que deu certo.